# Xtext IResourceValidator: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: validation, gradle, xtext, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a standalone xtext module (v2.9.0.beta3) which is built using Gradle. I implement the IResourceValidator.validate() function to validate a resource and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 65
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.impl.AbstractNode.getText(AbstractNode.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils.getTokenText(NodeModelUtils.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.impl.LinkingHelper.getCrossRefNodeAsString(LinkingHelper.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.impl.DefaultLinkingService.getCrossRefNodeAsString(DefaultLinkingService.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.impl.DefaultLinkingService.getLinkedObjects(DefaultLinkingService.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.getEObject(LazyLinkingResource.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.getEObject(LazyLinkingResource.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.doResolveLazyCrossReference(LazyLinkingResource.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.resolveLazyCrossReference(LazyLinkingResource.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.resolveLazyCrossReferences(LazyLinkingResource.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.EcoreUtil2.resolveLazyCrossReferences(EcoreUtil2.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.ResourceValidatorImpl.resolveProxies(ResourceValidatorImpl.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.validation.ResourceValidatorImpl.validate(ResourceValidatorImpl.java:75)
    at de.rwthaachen.dslprocessor.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:40)
    at aramis.service.dslprocessor.DslValidator.validateQueryString(DslValidator.java:19)
    at aramis.controller.AramisController.parseDsl(AramisController.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thank you in advance and any suggestion is really appreciated!